# Android: Carousel example change target 3.0 to 2.2

Tags: android, carousel

I tried carousel example from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=2&q=). The project target is up to 3. I need the carousel view like this. But my project target is 2.2. I tried to change target version. But I got compile error. Is that possible to change? Or is there other examples that support lower version?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't looked at the example, but if it indeed heavily relies on RenderScropt, as @Raghunandan suggested, you may be able to leverage the fact that it's part of the Support Library these days ([since September](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html)). // Edit: dunno where that other comment just disappeared to...?

Comment: yes, I did. but I cannot import some classes such as `android.renderscript.RenderScriptGL`. I cannot find in android ref documentation.

Comment: That's because it has been [deprecated since API level 16](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/16/changes/android.renderscript.RenderScriptGL.html). Anyways, if I recall correctly, only the RenderScript compute API is available in the Support Library, not any of the graphics APIs.